# Need optimisation for calculating and loading uitableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, nsdate

I am encountering a strange problem
Here is my scenario,i have a function called

```
-(void)fetch
{ 
   for (Dog *aDog in allDogs)
   {
       if([aDog getNumberOfDaysFromToday]>=0)
      {
        [filteredArray addObject:aDog];
      }
      else 
      {
        [tempArr addObject:aDog];
      }

   }
   [filteredArray addObjectsFromArray:tempArr];
}
```

the above method calculates numberOfDaysFromToday and returns an integer value.

I always need to calculate the numberOfDaysFromToday so that data is always up to date.

I have a UITableView which shows me the current data.

Now the problem:

Since i need to call the fetch method frequently i use viewWillAppear.
But when i navigate inside into some other view controller and come back,this method gets called always due to which my navigation speed gets hampered.It takes about 4-5 seconds just to navigate back because of the fetch method.
All i want to know is that,Is there any way i can speed up the getNumberOfDaysFromToday function?Or can any one tell me some other workaround?

getNumberOfDaysToday:

```
-(int)getNumberOfDaysFromToday{
    // Take the month and day of month of the event date
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd.MM"];
    NSString *eventDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:self.eventDate];
    NSDate *newEventDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:eventDateString];
    NSString *currentDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSDate *newCurrentDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:currentDateString];
    NSDateComponents *components;
    NSInteger days;

    components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components: NSDayCalendarUnit
                                                 fromDate: newCurrentDate   toDate: newEventDate options: 0];
    days = [components day];

    return days;

}
```

Comment: Show the code for `getNumberOfDaysFromToday` method. And how many items are you processing?

Comment: @Wain i have added the code and i am processing about 963 objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, to begin with, you should use instruments to profile the app and see exactly where all of the time is being spent.

For your `getNumberOfDaysFromToday`, creating a date formatter every time it's called is very expensive. You should create that once, store it and reuse the same one each time.

Switching back and forth between dates and strings is also very time consuming and wasteful. You're already using date components so you should expand that approach and use the date components to extract the bits of date that you need.

But, all that said, you shouldn't need to mess around with the dates anyway. You should just be able to use `components:fromDate:toDate:options:` with the passed date and the current date and it will do everything for you without all of the inefficiencies.

You could also pre-calculate the return value whenever the `eventDate` changes (which is presumably less often than you're showing views) which will cut down the time even more.

If you take one thing away from this though it should be profiling...

Answer (score 0):

NumberOfDays (the int value) doesn't change frequently even if you call it many times. 
You could schedule a recalculation of these days via [NSTimer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html) and define an interval suitable for your case.

ViewWillAppear shouldn't make so much calculations, IMHO.